# Why is the set $E$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I am having trouble understanding a proof presented in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.

The theorem states, if $f$ is a complex measurable function on $X$, there is a complex measurable function $\alpha$ on $X$ such that $\vert\alpha\vert=1$ and $f=\alpha\vert f\vert$.

The proof states: Let $E=\{x:f(x)=0\}$, let $Y$ be the complex plane with the origin removed, define $\varphi=\frac{z}{\vert z\vert}$ for $z\in Y$, and put
$$\alpha(x)=\varphi(f(x)+\chi_{E}(x))$$
Here $\chi_{E}(x)$ is the charateristic function of the set $E$. The proof then states that $E$ is measurable. I don't think I really understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, then $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable for every Borel set $B$. Now note that $E = f^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $\{0\}$ is a Borel set.